# How to modify a particular column based on the content of column of another file using Perl?

Tags: perl

I want to modify the column3 of file1 based on column2 of file2. Find the file1 difference between column4 and column3 (e.g. 302.48-301.85) called 'diff' and total of column2 and column3 of file2 (e.g. 292.73+1.38) called 'total'. If column4 value of file1 is greater than total of file2 then find the difference between column3 of file1 and total value called diff1. if (diff1 < diff) then modify the column3 value of file1 by column2 value of file2.

My problem is that file1 is not modified it shows:

```
en_4156 A en_4156_A **301.85 302.48** <O,en,F,en-F>  OH YEAH
```

Instead of this:

en_4156 A en_4156_A **299.22 302.48**   OH YEAH

`File1`:

```
;; LABEL "SW-F" "Switchboard Female" "Switchboard Female Caller"
;; LABEL "SW-M" "Switchboard Male" "Switchboard Male Caller"
en_4156 A en_4156_A 301.85 302.48 <O,en,F,en-F>  OH YEAH
```

`File2`:

```
en_4156 A 292.73 1.38 i 1.00
en_4156 A 294.14 1.62 know 1.00
en_4156 A 296.09 2.64 what 0.55
en_4156 A 299.22 2.58 oh 1.00
en_4156 A 301.80 1.83 yeah 1.00
en_4156 A 303.91 0.84 well 0.95
```

Updated `File1`:

```
;; LABEL "SW-F" "Switchboard Female" "Switchboard Female Caller"
;; LABEL "SW-M" "Switchboard Male" "Switchboard Male Caller"
en_4156 A en_4156_A 299.22 302.48 <O,en,F,en-F>  OH YEAH
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my ($ctm, $stm)=@ARGV;
open(CTM, "<$ctm");
open(STM, "+<$stm");
while (<CTM>) {
    ($wav, $channel, $start, $duration, $word, $score)=split(" ", $_);
    push @wav_c, $wav;
    push @channel_c, $channel;
    push @start_c, $start;
    push @dur_c, $duration;
    push @words, $word;
    push @scores, $score;
}
while (<STM>) {
    @line=split(" ", $_);
    push @wav_s, $line[0];
    push @channel_s, $line[1];
    push @start_s, $line[3];
    push @end_s, $line[4];
}
$ls=scalar @start_s;
$lc=scalar @start_c;

$j=0;

for ($i=0; $i<$ls; $i++) {
    while ($wav_s[$i] eq ";;") {
        $i++;
    }
    $diff=$end_s[$i]-$start_s[$i];
    while (($wav_s[$i] eq $wav_c[$j]) && ($channel_s[$i] eq $channel_c[$j])) {
        $total=$start_c[$j]+$dur_c[$j];
        if ($end_s[$i] > $total) {
            $diff1=$start_s[$i]-$total;
            if ($diff1 <= $diff) {
                $start_s[$i]=$start_c[$j];
                $j++;
            }
            else {
                $j++;
            }
        }
        else {
            $j++;
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: *Always* `use strict; use warnings;`!

Comment: Thanks @Biffen ..................

Comment: How do you know which line of file2 to use if they all start with `en_4156 A`???

Comment: @MattJacob i have mentioned the condition in above question

Comment: @ziks If your question was clear to begin with, I would not have asked. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Reading all the data into arrays, then trying to perform the required math on the data, then writing to the file is too tedious. It's easier to perform the calculations as you read the lines from the files.

My results file:

```
$ cat results.txt 
;; LABEL "SW-F" "Switchboard Female" "Switchboard Female Caller"
;; LABEL "SW-M" "Switchboard Male" "Switchboard Male Caller"
en_4156 A en_4156_A 299.22 302.48 <O,en,F,en-F> OH YEAH
```

Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use 5.020;
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;

my($file1, $file2, $results) = ('f1.txt', 'f2.txt', 'results.txt');
open my $FILE1, '<', $file1;
open my $FILE2, '<', $file2;
open my $RESULTS, '>', $results;

LINE_FILE1:
while(my $linef1 = <$FILE1>) {

    if($linef1 !~ /\Aen_\d{4}/) {  #if not a data line ...
        print {$RESULTS} $linef1;
        next LINE_FILE1;
    }

    my @colsf1 = split /\s+/, $linef1;
    my $diff = $colsf1[4] - $colsf1[3];

    while (my $linef2 = <$FILE2>) {
        my @colsf2 = split /\s+/, $linef2;
        my $total = $colsf2[2] + $colsf2[3];

        if($colsf1[4] > $total) {
            my $diff1 = $colsf1[3] - $total;
            $colsf1[3] = $colsf2[2] if $diff1 < $diff;
        }    
    }

    say {$RESULTS} "@colsf1";
}

close $FILE1;
close $FILE2;
close $RESULTS;
```

Comment: Thanks @7stud but  when i run this code then it's not compile successfully

Comment: @zika,  Why not?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oR7ZvbhUFko_s39FWWWAmWK_cszP6N6w see here