# How to print the text from column-6 to till end of line from a file using Perl?

Tags: perl

**File :**

```
;; LABEL "EN-F" "Callhome Female" "Callhome Female Caller"
;; LABEL "EN-M" "Callhome Male" "Callhome Male Caller"
;; LABEL "SW-F" "Switchboard Female" "Switchboard Female Caller"
;; LABEL "SW-M" "Switchboard Male" "Switchboard Male Caller"
en_4156 A en_4156_A 301.85 302.48 <O,en,F,en-F>  OH YEAH
en_4156 A en_4156_A 304.71 306.72 <O,en,F,en-F>  WELL I AM GOING TO HAVE MINE IN TWO MORE CLASSES
en_4156 A en_4156_A 307.63 311.16 <O,en,F,en-F>  NO I AM NOT WELL THEN I HAVE TO TAKE MY EXAMS MY ORALS BUT
en_4156 A en_4156_A 313.34 315.37 <O,en,F,en-F>  THAT IS KIND OF WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO DO
en_4156 A en_4156_A 316.83 319.20 <O,en,F,en-F>  I MIGHT EVEN WANT TO GO ON AND GET MY P H D
en_4156 A en_4156_A 321.55 322.16 <O,en,F,en-F>  IT IS JUST THAT
en_4156 A en_4156_A 323.05 327.38 <O,en,F,en-F>  I DO NOT KNOW IT IS SO COMFORTABLE WHERE I AM AND AND IF I
```

**Output File :**

```
;; LABEL "EN-F" "Callhome Female" "Callhome Female Caller"
;; LABEL "EN-M" "Callhome Male" "Callhome Male Caller"
;; LABEL "SW-F" "Switchboard Female" "Switchboard Female Caller"
;; LABEL "SW-M" "Switchboard Male" "Switchboard Male Caller"
en_4156  <O,en,F,en-F>  OH YEAH
en_4156  <O,en,F,en-F>  WELL I AM GOING TO HAVE MINE IN TWO MORE CLASSES
en_4156  <O,en,F,en-F>  NO I AM NOT WELL THEN I HAVE TO TAKE MY EXAMS MY ORALS BUT
en_4156  <O,en,F,en-F>  THAT IS KIND OF WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO DO
en_4156  <O,en,F,en-F>  I MIGHT EVEN WANT TO GO ON AND GET MY P H D
en_4156  <O,en,F,en-F>  IT IS JUST THAT
en_4156  <O,en,F,en-F>  I DO NOT KNOW IT IS SO COMFORTABLE WHERE I AM AND AND IF I
```

**Code :**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my ($file, $new_file)=@ARGV;
open(FILE, "<$file") or die "Unable to open $file";
open(NEW, ">$new_file") or die "Unable to open $new_file";
while (<FILE>) {
  @line=split(" ", $_);
  push @wav_s, $line[0];
  push @channel_s, $line[1];
  push @start_s, $line[3];
  push @end_s, $line[4];
  push @label, $line[5];
  push @txt, $line[6..$#line];
  if ($wav_s eq ";;") {
    print NEW $_;
  }
}
$ls=scalar @start_s;

for ($i=0; $i<$ls; $i++) {
  while ($wav_s[$i] eq ";;") {
    $i++;
  }
  print NEW "$wav_s[$i] $label[$i] $txt[$i]\n";
}
```

I want to print column-0, column-5 and all characters from column-6 to till end of file in a different file.
What is the right code for this problem ?

> Anyone can Complete this code .

Comment: `my @line = split /\s+/; my $index = shift @line; my $word = shift @line; print join(' ', @line) . "\n";`

Comment: `$line[2..]` in your code could be written as `$line[2..$#line]`

Comment: `The special variable $#array tells you the index of the last element of an array:` - from  perldoc perlintro
https://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Perl-variable-types

Comment: You should `use warnings; use strict;` in your code, and possible `use diagnostics;` to get detailed information about error messages.

Comment: And either `use autodie;` or check that your `open` calls finished successfully, as in: `open my $fh, "<$file" or die "Unable to open '$file' : $!"`

Comment: Thanks @xxfelixxx 
it's working properly. can you see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699784/how-to-modify-a-particular-column-based-on-the-content-of-column-of-another-file

Comment: According to your code **print join(' ', @line) . "\n";**  only print values in while loop. If i want to store these text in an array for further use then what can i use ?  @xxfelixxx

Comment: You can `push @txt, @line;`

Comment: it's not working correctly..

Comment: I cannot see what your are trying to show.

Comment: **File :**   

;; LABEL "SW-F" "Switchboard Female" "Switchboard Female Caller"  
;; LABEL "SW-M" "Switchboard Male" "Switchboard Male Caller"  
en_4156 A en_4156_A 301.85 302.48 <O,en,F,en-F>  OH YEAH  
en_4156 A en_4156_A 304.71 306.72 <O,en,F,en-F>  WELL I AM GOING TO HAVE MINE IN TWO MORE CLASSES  
en_4156 A en_4156_A 307.63 311.16 <O,en,F,en-F>  NO I AM NOT WELL THEN I HAVE TO TAKE MY EXAMS MY ORALS BUT  
en_4156 A en_4156_A 313.34 315.37 <O,en,F,en-F>  THAT IS KIND OF WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO DO

Comment: yes,this is an input file. Actually i want to comment it as a proper manner but i failed

Comment: You can edit your question, and put it there the same way, with 4 leading spaces on each line.

Comment: Edited my question @xxfelixxx

Comment: problem solved. Thanks for the help @xxfelixxx

Comment: You are welcome @ziks.  Glad you figured it all out.

Answer (score 0):

You're making this more complicated than it needs to be. It looks like you have fixed-width data, so why not extract it with [`unpack`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html)?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    if (/^;;/) {
        print;
        next;
    }

    my @fields = unpack('A8 A2 A10 A7 A7 A15 A*');
    print join('  ', @fields[0, 5, 6]),  "\n";
}

__DATA__
;; LABEL "EN-F" "Callhome Female" "Callhome Female Caller"
;; LABEL "EN-M" "Callhome Male" "Callhome Male Caller"
;; LABEL "SW-F" "Switchboard Female" "Switchboard Female Caller"
;; LABEL "SW-M" "Switchboard Male" "Switchboard Male Caller"
en_4156 A en_4156_A 301.85 302.48 <O,en,F,en-F>  OH YEAH
en_4156 A en_4156_A 304.71 306.72 <O,en,F,en-F>  WELL I AM GOING TO HAVE MINE IN TWO MORE CLASSES
en_4156 A en_4156_A 307.63 311.16 <O,en,F,en-F>  NO I AM NOT WELL THEN I HAVE TO TAKE MY EXAMS MY ORALS BUT
en_4156 A en_4156_A 313.34 315.37 <O,en,F,en-F>  THAT IS KIND OF WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO DO
en_4156 A en_4156_A 316.83 319.20 <O,en,F,en-F>  I MIGHT EVEN WANT TO GO ON AND GET MY P H D
en_4156 A en_4156_A 321.55 322.16 <O,en,F,en-F>  IT IS JUST THAT
en_4156 A en_4156_A 323.05 327.38 <O,en,F,en-F>  I DO NOT KNOW IT IS SO COMFORTABLE WHERE I AM AND AND IF I
```

Output:

```
;; LABEL "EN-F" "Callhome Female" "Callhome Female Caller"
;; LABEL "EN-M" "Callhome Male" "Callhome Male Caller"
;; LABEL "SW-F" "Switchboard Female" "Switchboard Female Caller"
;; LABEL "SW-M" "Switchboard Male" "Switchboard Male Caller"
en_4156  <O,en,F,en-F>  OH YEAH
en_4156  <O,en,F,en-F>  WELL I AM GOING TO HAVE MINE IN TWO MORE CLASSES
en_4156  <O,en,F,en-F>  NO I AM NOT WELL THEN I HAVE TO TAKE MY EXAMS MY ORALS BUT
en_4156  <O,en,F,en-F>  THAT IS KIND OF WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO DO
en_4156  <O,en,F,en-F>  I MIGHT EVEN WANT TO GO ON AND GET MY P H D
en_4156  <O,en,F,en-F>  IT IS JUST THAT
en_4156  <O,en,F,en-F>  I DO NOT KNOW IT IS SO COMFORTABLE WHERE I AM AND AND IF I
```